# What does < variable, variable > mean?

Tags: sql, oracle

I understand in SQL that <> means not equal to. Does is still mean the same thing if there are variables declared in between?

See below an example:

```
where OBJECTNAME = 'example' and time > validdate and validtime < date;
```

Comment: `time > validdate` simply means `(the value of) "time" is greater than (the value of) "validdate"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is [**logical conjuction**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_conjunction) and comparison operators (> greater than, < less than).

```
WHERE OBJECTNAME = 'example' 
  AND time > validdate 
  AND validtime < date;
```

It means that all conditions have to be true to evaluate entire formula as true.